# jquery close to form data in a table on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[`jsfiddle link`](http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/S4FT7/)

I want above jsfiddle example to have a close button like in the picture at the end of the record and when the close button is clicked I want to remove the record.

Any one can help me to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an element with the `X`, and an event handler that removes the TR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#details').on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    })

    $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        var st = '';
        $('#myForm input[type=text],input[type=password],select').each(function(){
            st = st+ '<td>'+$(this).val()+'</td>';
            $(this).val('');
        });
        var remove = $('<td />', {text : 'X', 'class': 'remove'});
        $('#details').append( $('<tr />').append(st, remove) );
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/S4FT7/65/)